# Android Custom-Time Notification Service/Broadcast/AlarmManager

Tags: android, service, notifications, alarmmanager, receiver

My goal is to implement a notification that appears on a user-chosen time of day.
I already tried `Service`, this works but the problem is it needs a lot of background process (the code is below) and the other one was `AlarmManager` but this seems not to work properly, **especially on API 19+**. I could not find an up-to-date well-coded tutorial or a useful answer on a similar question here on stackoverflow so I turn to you.

All of you know: If a friend text you an Whatsapp you get a notification even when your phone is off or in sleep(screen off).
Im sure some of you already implemented something like this.

The task precisely:
My app shall notify the user **every day once** about his scheduled events in his calendar.

For example:
He has chosen 13:00 (I'm using always 24h format) to remind him about his events.
He scheduled 2 events on next day: 
- Drive kids to school
- Go to gym

Next day at 13:00 the app shows a notification:
"You have two events for today!: 1)... 2)..."

Filling the notification with the informations is not the problem. This works fine and I tested it a lot.
Im missing only the well-coded background-thread thats watching for the user-chosen time to show the notification.

*Please note*:

- The TimerTask ticks-intervall is 1000ms (1second). Im sure this is not well-coded but it works. **But Im searching for a better and more battery-friendly solution.**
- Moreover I added the **"android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"** and **"android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"** permission.
- The service is flagged as **START_STICKY**

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service android:name=".services.NotificationService" android:exported="false"/>

        <receiver android:name=".services.BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        //Other Activities

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**BootReceiver:**

```
public class BootReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, NotificationService.class));
    }
}
```

**NotificationService:**

```
public class NotificationService extends Service{

    private Calendar currentCalendar, plannedCalendar;

    public static final String FILENAME_SETTINGS = "MySettings";
    private static final int MODE_PRIVATE = 0;
    SharedPreferences data;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private Timer timer;
    private TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            data = getSharedPreferences(FILENAME_SETTINGS, MODE_PRIVATE);

            int plannedHour = data.getInt("alarm_hour", 0);
            int plannedMinute = data.getInt("alarm_minute", 0);
            plannedCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
            plannedCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, plannedMinute);
            plannedCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, plannedHour);
            plannedCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            plannedCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            //Kalender aktualisieren
            currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
            currentCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            //Check ob es 00:00:00 Uhr ist --> Notification wieder erwuenscht!!!
            currentCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            currentCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            if(currentCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND) == 0 && currentCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) == 0 && currentCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == 0){
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("notification", false);
                editor.apply();
            }
            //Nochmal aktualisieren weil durch den "Check" manipuliert wurde
            currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
            currentCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());


            if((currentCalendar.getTimeInMillis() >= plannedCalendar.getTimeInMillis()) & !data.getBoolean("notification", false)) {
                PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeLock");
                wakeLock.acquire();

                notification();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("notification", true);
                editor.apply();

                wakeLock.release();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        try{
            timer.cancel();
            timerTask.cancel();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent("Intent");
        intent.putExtra("VALUE", "blalal");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    public void notification(){
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, LiveSelectActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pen = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.hineweisTrainingsGeplant))
                .setContentText("Content")
                .setContentIntent(pen)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_add_white_24dp);

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(1, notification);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: "I already tried Service, this works" -- not on Android 6.0+. On older devices, it can work reliably, but users will threaten your life for the power drain that you cause. "and the other one was AlarmManager but this seems not to work properly, especially on API 19+" -- that depends on what you use. `setAlarmClock()` is reliable, for example, though it has UI elements that are very much tied to the "alarm clock" metaphor. "If a friend text you an Whatsapp you get a notification even when your phone is off or in sleep(screen off)" -- they use Google Cloud Messaging, AFAIK.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the quick advice. I tried AlarmManager in every imaginal way: setExakt(), setInexakt(), setInExaktRepeating() and so on. the problem was, when the phone is in sleep, it does not wake it up, even with RTC_WAKE_UP. Moreover it i did not find a solution for the api 19+ problem. because after one notification you have to set next manually. Thats why I set on services.

Comment: "when the phone is in sleep, it does not wake it up, even with RTC_WAKE_UP" -- it does for other developers, at least prior to Android 6.0+ (where Doze mode/app standby start to interfere), and when you don't have bugs. "Moreover it i did not find a solution for the api 19+ problem. because after one notification you have to set next manually" -- again, it works for other developers.

Comment: @CommonsWare But when the phone restarts, will the process get started automatically again and show the next notification or has the user to start the app again?

Comment: Neither. Usually the app registers for `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` and reschedules the alarm at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule `Intent`s that your service will receive and process at a desired time. It does work if configured properly.

Comment: I already mentioned that I used AlarmManager. I had multiple problems especially with my api 21 device.^^

Comment: That means only one thing - you have not configured it properly. Refer to @CommonsWare comment to your question